# Camel Undertow Websockets

Tags: websocket, apache-camel, undertow

How do I enable websockets in Undertow when used with Camel

These are the ways I tried.

```
from("undertow:http://localhost:7766").transform(simple("Test"));
from("undertow:ws://localhost:7766").transform(simple("Test"));
```

When i try to access websockets, am getting an error "Unexpected response code 200"

I dont see any option in camel spec as well, to specifically say , this is a Websocket endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets is not supported in camel-undertow. At this time of writing its only for HTTP/HTTPS protocol.

You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket at Apache Camel to ask for websocket support.